# Duplicate notification GCM android application

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

*Getting twice GCM PUSH notification when application is closed or application is in background
plese help :( 
*

Comment: i change GCM service to FCM service and it is OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i change GCM service to FCM service and it is OK